# Semi-supervised Naive Bayes with NLTK

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk, naivebayes, unsupervised-learning

I have built a semi-supervised version of NLTK's Naive Bayes in Python based on the EM (expectation-maximization algorithm). However, in some iterations of EM I am getting negative log-likelihoods (the log-likelihoods of EM must be positive in every iteration), therefore I believe that there must be some mistakes in my code. After carefully reviewing my code, I have no idea why is this happenning. It would be really appreciated if someone could spot any mistakes in my code below:

([Reference material of semi-supervised Naive Bayes](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~xfern/classes/cs534/notes/semi-supervised1.pdf))

**EM-algorithm main loop**

```
#initial assumptions:
#Bernoulli NB: only feature presence (value 1) or absence (value None) is computed 

#initial data:
#C: classifier trained with labeled data
#labeled_data: an array of tuples (feature dic, label)
#features: dictionary that outputs feature dictionary for a given document id  

for iteration in range(1, self.maxiter):    

  #Expectation: compute probabilities for each class for each unlabeled document
  #An array of tuples (feature dictionary, probability dist) is built       
  unlabeled_data = [(features[id],C.prob_classify(features[id])) for id in U]

  #Maximization: given the probability distributions of previous step,
  #update label, feature-label counts and update classifier C
  #gen_freqdists is a custom function, see below
  #gen_probdists is the original NLTK function
  l_freqdist_act,ft_freqdist_act, ft_values_act = self.gen_freqdists(labeled_data,unlabeled_data)
  l_probdist_act, ft_probdist_act = self.gen_probdists(l_freqdist_act, ft_freqdist_act, ft_values_act, ELEProbDist)
  C = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier(l_probdist_act, ft_probdist_act)                    

  #Compute log-likelihood 
  #NLTK Naive bayes classifier prob_classify func gives logprob(class) + logprob(doc|class))
  #for labeled data, sum logprobs output by the classifier for the label
  #for unlabeled data, sum logprobs output by the classifier for each label
  log_lh = sum([C.prob_classify(ftdic).prob(label) for (ftdic,label) in labeled_data])      
  log_lh += sum([C.prob_classify(ftdic).prob(label) for (ftdic,ignore) in unlabeled_data for label in l_freqdist_act.samples()])

  #Continue until convergence               
  if log_lh_old == "first": 
    if self.debug: print "\tM: #iteration 1",log_lh,"(FIRST)"
    log_lh_old =  log_lh            
  else:
    log_lh_diff = log_lh - log_lh_old
    if self.debug: print "\tM: #iteration",iteration,log_lh_old,"->",log_lh,"(",log_lh_diff,")"
    if log_lh_diff < self.log_lh_diff_min: break        
    log_lh_old =  log_lh
```

**Custom function gen-freqdists, used to create needed frequency distributions**

```
def gen_freqdists(self, instances_l, instances_ul):     
    l_freqdist = FreqDist() #frequency distrib. of labels
    ft_freqdist= defaultdict(FreqDist) #dictionary of freq. distrib. for ft-label pairs
    ft_values = defaultdict(set) #dictionary of possible values for each ft (only 1/None)
    fts = set() #set of all fts

    #counts for labeled data
    for (ftdic,label) in instances_l:
      l_freqdist.inc(label,1)
      for f in ftdic.keys():
        fts.add(f) 
        ft_freqdist[label,f].inc(1,1)
        ft_values[f].add(1)

    #counts for unlabeled data
    #we must compute maximum a posteriori label estimate
    #and update label/ft occurrences accordingly
    for (ftdic,probs) in instances_ul:
      map_l = probs.max() #label with highest probability
      map_p = probs.prob(map_l) #probability of map_l
      l_freqdist.inc(map_l,count=map_p)
      for f in ftdic.keys():
        fts.add(f)
        ft_freqdist[map_l,f].inc(1,count=map_p)             
        ft_values[f].add(1)

    #features not appearing in documents get implicit None values
    for l in l_freqdist.samples():
    num_samples = l_freqdist[l] 
    for f in fts:
      count = ft_freqdist[l,f].N()              
      ft_freqdist[l,f].inc(None, num_samples-count)
      ft_values[f].add(None)    

    #return computed frequency distributions
    return l_freqdist, ft_freqdist, ft_values
```

Comment: You don't actually need to compute the log-likelihood to test for convergence of EM; you can also check whether the outcomes from `prob_classify`, or even the probabilities inside the model, stabilize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're summing the wrong values.

This is your code that is supposed to compute the sum of the log probs:

```
  #Compute log-likelihood 
  #NLTK Naive bayes classifier prob_classify func gives logprob(class) + logprob(doc|class))
  #for labeled data, sum logprobs output by the classifier for the label
  #for unlabeled data, sum logprobs output by the classifier for each label

  log_lh = sum([C.prob_classify(ftdic).prob(label) for (ftdic,label) in labeled_data])
  log_lh += sum([C.prob_classify(ftdic).prob(label) for (ftdic,ignore) in unlabeled_data for label in l_freqdist_act.samples()])
```

According to the NLTK documentation for [prob_classify](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.classify.naivebayes.NaiveBayesClassifier-class.html#prob_classify) (on NaiveBayesClassifier) a [ProbDistI](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.probability.ProbDistI-class.html) object is returned (*not* `logprob(class) + logprob(doc|class)`). When you get this object, You're calling the `prob` method on it for a given label. You probably want to call `logprob`, and  negate that return as well.

Comment: +1, but even if you'd call `logprob`, you'd still not get the figure the OP wants. The result from `prob_classify` does not represent `P(class)*P(doc|class)`, but `P(class)*P(doc|class)/sum(P(doc|class') for class' in classes)`. I'm guessing it would converge to the same set of parameters, though.

Comment: @larsmans, good catch. You could estimate `P(doc) = sum(P(doc|class)) ` from the data and multiply it out if you truly needed the LLH. I suspect you're correct in that it won't make a large difference in the final convergence.

Comment: Thanks, @seggy and @larsmans! I was mistaken in the log-likelihood computation. Just to make sure one last thing, do you think that the function gen-freqdists is ok ? I think that increasing the label/label-freq counts of the MAP class for the unlabeled data, and then updating the None values accordingly is enough, but I am not completely sure of this.